# Generate XML and HTML from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xml, xslt

Need to generate an **html report** from **XML** and corresponding **XSL** butI have to use memorystream instead of IO File write on server directories. For the most part I managed to create an xml

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
wSettings.Indent = true;
using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms,wSettings))
{
      /**
          creating xml here
      **/
      writer.Flush();
      writer.Close();
}
return ms; // returning the memory stream to another function
           // to create html

// This Function creates 
protected string ConvertToHtml(MemoryStream xmlOutput)
{
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(xmlOutput);
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(xmlOutput);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transform.Load(reportDir + "MyXslFile.xsl");
        transform.Transform(xDoc, null, writer);
        xmlOutput.Position = 1;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlOutput);
        return sr.RearToEnd();
}
```

Somewhere along the line I am messing up with creating the **HTML Report** and cant figure out how to send that file to client end. I dont have much experience working with memorystream. So, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're completely bypassing your transform here:

```
// This Function creates 
protected string ConvertToHtml(MemoryStream xmlOutput)
{
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(xmlOutput);
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(xmlOutput);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transform.Load(reportDir + "MyXslFile.xsl");
        transform.Transform(xDoc, null, writer);

        // These lines are the problem
        //xmlOutput.Position = 1;
        //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlOutput);
        //return sr.RearToEnd();

        return writer.ToString()
}
```

Also, calling Flush right before you call Close on a writer is redundant as Close implies a flush operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie. It seems writer.ToString() is generating my desired html output but how would I be able to render in a way so that it opens up in another browser tab as another html file. Any idea ??

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't from the server side. You can cause the browser to present the file open/save dialog by specifying a Content-Disposition in the HTTP header, but to actually cause a new window or tab to appear, it has to be done with client-side code. There are a variety of ways to do it, like specifying a target attribute on a hyperlink or in a window.open javascript call.

Comment: Specifying Content-Disposition in the HTTP header would resolve my issue here. And I am trying **Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + writer.ToString() + ".html");** but in the end I am not getting an html file but a file with all html tags in it. Any idea ?? Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `Response.Clear()` before doing the other stuff with the Response? Also, if you check your content in the debugger before outputting it does the content look ok? You could possibly still have a problem with your transform code in the xsl. If that's the case I'd recommended posting another question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want to achieve but using both XmlDocument and XPathDocument to load from the same memory stream does not make sense I think. And I would set the MemoryStream to Position 0 before loading from it so either have the function creating and writing to the memory stream ensure that it sets the Position to zero or do that before you call Load on the XmlDocument or before you create an XPathDocument, depending on what input tree model you want to use.

Comment: Pardon me, I was trying both because an error popped up saying "Root Element is missing. Forgot to comment it out. I can use any one of 'em. In this case however I used XmlDocument.

Comment: The error "root element is missing" is caused by the position of the memory stream, it is positioned at the end after the XML you wrote to it so you need to ensure you position the stream at position 0 before you try to load XML from it.